# Yii add link on CDetailView Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm using zii.widgets.CDetailView

When I'm trying to add Link with target ='_blank'. 
this never working although I'm added the target blank. 
The link always open in the same tab

here's my code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'table table-condensed table-hover'),
'attributes'=>array(
    'idproduct',
    array(
        'name'=>'Preview',
        'type'=>'html',
        'value'=>(
            (!empty($model->picture->filename_thumb))?
            CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/product/".$model->picture->filename_thumb,"Preview",array("width"=>"75px","height"=>"75px")):"No Image"             
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'Company',
        'type'=>'html',
        'value'=>$model->company->name,
    ),

    array(
        'name'=>'Product URL',
        'type'=>'html',
        'value'=>CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Click Here'), "http://localhost/voucher/".$model->urlproduct, array("class"=>"btn btn-info","target"=>"_blank")) 
    ),
),
```

));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array(
    'name'=>'Product URL',
    'type'=>'html',
    'value'=>CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Click Here'), "http://localhost/voucher/".$model->urlproduct, array("class"=>"btn btn-info","target"=>"_blank")) 
),
```

change the 'type'=>'html',

to 'type'=>'raw',